# How to be specific about network type whether it is wifi or mobile data in obj C

Tags: objective-c

I am implementing a code where I need to know whether I am connected via WiFi or Mobile Data.
I am using following code but it is only giving me network type as wifi even if I am connected via mobile data.
The code is as follows:

```
- (void)logReachability:(Reachability *)reachability {
    NSString *whichReachabilityString = nil;

    if (reachability == self.hostReachability) {
        whichReachabilityString = @"www.apple.com";
        NSLog(@" 1");
    } else if (reachability == self.internetReachability) {
        whichReachabilityString = @"The Internet";
        NSLog(@" 2");
    } else if (reachability == self.wifiReachability) {
        whichReachabilityString = @"Local Wi-Fi";
        NSLog(@" 3");
    }

    NSString *howReachableString = nil;

    switch (reachability.currentReachabilityStatus) {
        case NotReachable: {
            howReachableString = @"not reachable";
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN: {
            howReachableString = @"reachable by cellular data";
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi: {
            howReachableString = @"reachable by Wi-Fi";
            break;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@" Reachable Via :%@ ", howReachableString);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This

```
-(void)isNetworkReachable
 {
        NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [[Reachability  reachabilityForInternetConnection] currentReachabilityStatus];
        if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWWAN){
            NSLog(@"LAN/WAN network....");
        }
        else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFi){
            NSLog(@"Wifi network....");
        }
 }
```

Comment: No it is not working. Even if I am on mobile data I am getting the Wifi Log.